# Going to the Mikva for fun

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath, niddah

I am aware that a pregnant/breastfeeding/post menopausal woman who is not menstruating does not need to go to the Mikva, HOWEVER, I am wondering if theoretically it would be permissible for her to go, just for the spa-like benefits.

Say a woman has multiple children and needs some alone time to get away, would she be allowed to go to her local Mikva and shower peacefully, groom herself peacefully, and immerse with no bracha?

Comment: Halachic aspect or local rules aspect?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be permissible to dip in a pool of water?

Comment: Contact your local mikveh. While in theory an unnecessary dunker doesn't hurt the mikveh (though it does mean one fewer slot and more work for the attendants)... they may have a policy of "we only deal with those who need this from a halachic perspective" ... that's a local mikveh's call. Yoatzot.org notes some have a custom to go to the mikveh once during the ninth month of pregnancy. https://www.yoatzot.org/questions-and-answers/1668/ But as dunking here is of no halachic value, I can't help but wonder if a regular spa would be better plan?

Comment: There's a custom that a woman goes to the mikvah when she enters her 9th (8th?) month as a segulah for an easy labor.

Comment: The Ben Ish Chai says all women.except active d'orayta niddot should use the mikvah before the Yomim Noraim. Good luck using that to get into your local mikvah, however

Comment: @יהושעק Yoatzot.org does mention it as a possibility, with the caveat "if okay with your local mikveh."

Comment: Is it that the only place where a mom can get a quiet hour to herself is the mikveh?